# How do I find my screenshot directory (I already changed it)

Tags: screen-capture

How do I find my screenshot directory? I already know how to change the screenshot directory, because I did it a long time ago, but now I don't know what it is, because I've done it on several different computers.

Answer (score 1):

If you've changed the location, then
`defaults read com.apple.screencapture location`
will show you.

If you haven't changed it, i.e. it's still set to the default Desktop & has never been redirected, it will error with
`The domain/default pair of (/Users/[user]/Library/Preferences/com.apple.screencapture, location) does not exist`

Answer (score 0):

You could change it again to a folder you can find, perhaps the previous location will also be shown. If you haven't changed it on your current mac, screenshots wil be stored at your desktop