# Screenshots not appearing on desktop

Tags: mac, folders, screen-capture

When I take a screenshot with my Mac, the screenshots are not appearing on my desktop. Could the screenshot destination location have been changed on Mac? Is this a common problem?

Comment: see http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/222662/85275 though if you haven't changed it, try rebooting & see if they appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reset the default location of screenshots to your Desktop, type this in Terminal:

`defaults write com.apple.screencapture location ~/Desktop`

then restart.